# Attach custom (hidden) data to an image in Microsoft Word Add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office, docx

I'm attempting to write an Office Add-in for Microsoft Word (2007 and higher) using VSTO on Visual Studio 2010 and C#.

The add-in will insert images into the document that are downloaded from the internet (from a custom CGI script).  These images update daily, so I have added a button to 'refresh' all the images from the server upon request.  However, I'm not certain how to 'store' the original identifier for the image along with the image embedded in the document to know which image to get from the server.  The identifier can be anywhere from a few characters to several hundred (~200) characters long, but are an ASCII identifier.

Currently I insert the picture like so:

```
    public void InsertPictureFromIdentifier(String identifier)
    {
        Document vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);

        Word.Selection selection = this.Application.Selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.Range != null)
        {
            // Insert the picture control
            var picture = vstoDocument.Controls.AddPictureContentControl(selection.Range, "mypic");
            // And update the image
            UpdatePicture(picture, identifier);
         }
    }
```

Then UpdatePicture is called both on the initial insert, and upon refresh, to update the image:

```
    public void UpdatePicture(PictureContentControl picture, string identifier)
    {
        const int BytesToRead = 1000000;

        // Download the image from the scrip
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://my.server.com/graph.cgi?"+identifier);
        var response = request.GetResponse();
        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var reader = new BinaryReader(responseStream);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        Byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[BytesToRead];

        // Transfer to a memory stream
        var bytesRead = reader.Read(byteBuffer, 0, BytesToRead);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            memoryStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = reader.Read(byteBuffer, 0, BytesToRead);
        }

        // Set the image from the memory stream
        picture.Image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(memoryStream);
    }
```

As you can see I pass the identifier into update - but the question is how to get that identifier back from the 'picture'  I've inserted the next day on a refresh.  I've tried using the picture's Tag, but that is limited to 64 characters.  I've even tried using the picture's Title property, but that seems to silently fail on some other maximum limit.

The identifier will need to be persisted between save / loads, move with the image in the document, and be invisible (I can't just add text after the image with the identifier).